# Displaying Title in Title Tag on Edit page?

Tags: wp-admin

I want to change the **title tag** in the edit page, so that I can read the title of my edit page in my browser tabs:

```
function edit_admin_title_tag() {
global $post;
    $title_tag = '<title>'. $post->post_title .'</title>';
   echo  $title_tag;
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'edit_admin_title_tag' );
```

How can I delete/overwrite the default title tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying Post Title on Post Edit page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/displaying-post-title-on-post-edit-page)

Comment: Thanks fayazmiraz. But this solution does not display the title in the title tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my the solution (filter hook admin_title) in [Change page title in admin area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17025/change-page-title-in-admin-area)

```
function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title) {
  global $post, $action;
  if($action == 'edit' ) {
    $admin_title_tag = '* ' . $post->post_title;
    return $admin_title_tag; 
  }
}
add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);
```